# How do I get 2 way photo syncing with dropbox?

Tags: sync, photos, dropbox

I have Dropbox auto uploading photos that I take.

What I'd like is to have deletions or reorganizations of my photos on the phone to be reflected in Dropbox and also the other way around?

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. [Dropbox says](https://www.dropbox.com/help/288):

> Dropbox will not delete files from your mobile device after they are uploaded. The files on your camera, phone, tablet, or SD Card will remain on your device until you remove them manually.

To do this, you will need a third-party app, like [Dropsync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync&hl=en).